# URL in browser web2py

Tags: web2py

IS there way to launch application without specifying the URL in browser.
e..g  I have an app fordemo
In view show.html and in controller default.py show method is there.
I want to launch show.html page without specifying the /fordemo/default/show URL in browser.

Comment: Do you mean they way web2py opens a page in the default browser on startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is you want */fordemo/default/show* to be the default function when you load up web2py, or when you enter your domain name on the browser. In that case you need to create a file called **routes.py** in your root web2py folder (the same place where web2py.py or web2py.exe is). In routes.py you'll need something like the following:

```
#routes.py
default_application = "fordemo"
default_controller = "default"
default_function = "show"
```

You must restart web2py for changes to take affect.